# how to fetch the linkedIn contacts in your IOS app?

Tags: xcode, ios7, ios6, ios8, xcode6

i want to get the linkedIn contacts of logIn user & after that if we click the contact person then its message box is open. 
The code I'm using is as follows:

```
OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestTokenURL consumer:self.consumer token:nil callback:linkedInCallbackURL signatureProvider:nil]; 
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];


NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections"]; [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"]; 
OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
 [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request delegate:self didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenResult:didFinish:) didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenResult:didFail:)];
 [request release]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the Api documentation of LinkedIn. You will have to make a webrequest and fetch the answer.

Comment: Do you know how to make a webrequest? Just do it and get the answer

Comment: I'm tempted to flag your answer as "low quality", @Etixpp. Could you come up with a more detailed answer than "Read documentation"?

Comment: i'll send u what i get in response

Comment: @Michael Dautermann as long as he provides no code and no exact problem i cant. This site isnt for free coding service

Comment: updates recieved {
  "errorCode": 0,
  "message": "Could not find person based on: ~",
  "requestId": "4ZDWU3UXVX",
  "status": 404,
  "timestamp": 1413450085075
}
2014-10-16 20:11:44.845 Bond[1253:60b] INFO:(
)
2014-10-16 20:11:44.889 Bond[1253:60b] 0
2014-10-16 20:11:44.901 Bond[1253:60b] 0
2014-10-16 20:11:44.943 Bond[1253:60b] 0
2014-10-16 20:11:45.597 Bond[1253:901b] SYNCOPERATION: GET CONTACTS
2014-10-16 20:11:46.200 Bond[1253:60b] INFO: GoogleAnalytics 3.03a -[GAIBatchingDispatcher didSendHits:response:data:error:](GAIBatchingDispatcher.m:157): Hit(s) dispatched: HTTP status 200

Comment: It looks to me, that you use a wrong name or other for finding the person necesarry parameters

Comment: OAMutableURLRequest *request =
    [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:requestTokenURL
                                    consumer:self.consumer
                                       token:nil
                                    callback:linkedInCallbackURL
                           signatureProvider:nil];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

Comment: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections"];
 [request setValue:@"json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"x-li-format"];
    
    OADataFetcher *fetcher = [[OADataFetcher alloc] init];
    [fetcher fetchDataWithRequest:request
                         delegate:self
                didFinishSelector:@selector(requestTokenResult:didFinish:)
                  didFailSelector:@selector(requestTokenResult:didFail:)];
    [request release];
}

Comment: It is possible to fetch linkedIn contacts in iOS app ?